# why is this happening? : TypeError: Cannot read property 'username' of undefined in REACT

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to make a messenger clone app in react and I don't really know what happened to get this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'username' of undefined

why is it suddenly giving this error ??

please have a look!

so i have two files the first is ***App.js***:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Button, InputLabel, Input, FormControl } from "@material-ui/core";
import "./App.css";
import Message from "./Message";
import db from "./firebase";
import firebase from "firebase";
import FlipMove from "react-flip-move";

function App() {
  const [input, setInput] = useState("");
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState([{}]);
  const [username, setUsername] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    db.collection("messages")
      .orderBy("timestamp", "desc")
      .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
        setMessages(
          snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({ id: doc.data, message: doc.data() }))
        );
      });
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    setUsername(prompt("please enter your name"));
  }, []);

  const sendMessage = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    db.collection("messages").add({
      message: input,
      username: username,
      timestamp: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
    });
    setInput("");
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello</h1>
      <h2>welcome {username}</h2>
      <form className="send">
        <FormControl>
          <InputLabel>Enter a message..</InputLabel>
          <Input
            value={input}
            onChange={(event) => setInput(event.target.value)}
          />
          <Button
            disabled={!input}
            variant="contained"
            color="primary"
            type="submit"
            onClick={sendMessage}
          >
            Send Message
          </Button>
        </FormControl>
      </form>

      <FlipMove>
        {messages.map(({ id, message }) => (
          <Message key={id} username={username} message={message} />
        ))}
      </FlipMove>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

and the Second one is ***Message.js*** which the error occurs in:

```
import { Card, CardContent, Typography } from "@material-ui/core";
import React, { forwardRef } from "react";
import "./Message.css";

const Message = forwardRef(({ message, username }, ref) => {
  const isUser = username === message.username;
  return (
    <div ref={ref} className={`message ${isUser && "message_user"}`}>
      <Card className={isUser ? "message_userCard" : "message_guestCard"}>
        <CardContent>
          <Typography color="white" variant="h5" component="h2">
            {message.username}: {message.message}
          </Typography>
        </CardContent>
      </Card>
    </div>
  );
});

export default Message;
```

the error is in this line `const isUser = username  === message.username;`

Comment: `useState([{}])` what is that empty object in there supposed to do?

Comment: thank you dear sir for commenting , the thing is i'm new to react and i'm following a simple tutorial , what i get from this part is that this empty object is supposed to be filled with the data that is coming from the firebase

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means the `message` value that gets passed to the `Message` component as a prop is undefined.

So when you iterate through messages here, at least one of the objects in your `messages` array does not have a defined value for its `message` key:

```
      <FlipMove>
        {messages.map(({ id, message }) => (
          <Message key={id} username={username} message={message} />
        ))}
      </FlipMove>
```

Try printing out your entire `messages` array before the `render()` func and checking what values exist.

Try changing this line:

```
const [messages, setMessages] = useState([{}]);
```

To this:

```
const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);
```

EDIT: The problem was that this following line means you are initializing your `messages` array to this: `[{}]`:

```
const [messages, setMessages] = useState([{}]);
```

This means your array has one element in it, an empty object {}.
It will stay like this until your database read completes and populates your array with your real data. So the first time around, your render function will try to make sense of this array that only has this one empty object in it.

So when you iterate through it like this:

```
        {messages.map(({ id, message }) => (
          <Message key={id} username={username} message={message} />
        ))}
```

Then for every element, it will look for an `id` and `message` property because of this destructuring assignment (look that term up if you're not sure what that is):

```
({ id, message })
```

So because you start out with that one empty object element in your array, it will look for a `.message` property for that empty object, which won't exist. It will be `undefined`. This `undefined` gets passed as a prop to your `Message` component. Then in your `Message` component, this line:

```
const isUser = username === message.username;
```

Tries to access a `.username` property on `undefined`, because remember, `message = undefined`, because that's what you passed inadvertently as the prop. Thats why the error complains that it can't find a `username` property on something that is `undefined`:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'username' of undefined
```

Comment: thank you dear sir for taking the time to help, can you please be more clear because i'm new to react , and sorry for taking some of your time

Comment: thanks dear sir for helping , that did it and made the error disappear , can you suggest a certain place to learn react XD thank you for your time again sir

Comment: no problem, when you get errors like this, even my answer fixed it, try to go back and figure out why your error got fixed. I'll update answer with what the problem here was, try to go back through it and make sure you fully understand it and keep doing that with every debug issue you come across :)